# React emotion-theming not working during server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, emotion

I'm migrating from React Emotion 9 to Emotion 10 following this guide https://emotion.sh/docs/migrating-to-emotion-10

It should enable SSR by default, however, it doesn't seem to work with emotion-theming because I don't have access to "props.theme" in styled components. Styled components, however, work as expected with emotion-theming client side.

What are the possible reasons?

Standard code is used

```
const App = (theme) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        ...
    </ThemeProvider>
);
```

```
const app = <App theme={theme} />
const html = renderToString(app);
```

Some error logs:

```
at handleInterpolation (webpack:///./node_modules/@emotion/serialize/dist/serialize.esm.js?:143:24)
    at serializeStyles (webpack:///./node_modules/@emotion/serialize/dist/serialize.esm.js?:253:15)
    at Object.eval [as children] (webpack:///./node_modules/@emotion/styled-base/dist/styled-base.esm.js?:114:100)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/www/sites/base_web/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3412:55)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/www/sites/base_web/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3161:29)
    at renderToString (/www/sites/base_web/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3646:27)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
  import { renderStylesToString } from 'emotion-server'
  import App from './App'

  const html = renderStylesToString(renderToString(<App />))
```

does this work?